# Returning my printed output in pairs as tuples?

Tags: python, output, tuples

```
for div in soup.find_all('table', class_="W(100%)"):
       for y in div.find_all('td'):
           print (y.text)
```

returns an output of:

```
Previous Close
38.08
Open
38.23
Bid
37.67 x 100
Ask
38.16 x 500
Day's Range
37.35 - 38.25
52 Week Range
23.50 - 40.92
Volume
29,152
Avg. Volume
118,446
Market Cap
1.66B
```

I want to return the output as

```
(Previous Close, 38.08)
(Open, 38.23)
(Bid, 37.67 x 100)
```

I honestly have no idea how to tackle this. 
I thought about implementing an and odd and even counter, but even then, how would I join the previous entry with the next entry?

Comment: Why not loop over the `tr`s and then print the appropriate `td`s ?

Comment: if you always want two elements, why not append it to a list and print the list, if its len() is ==2? (and clear the list after printing)

Comment: @dede   I see what you saying. I will try that out and see if I can implement it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for *rows* (`<tr>` elements), not cells; you can then group cells per row:

```
for row in soup.select('table.W(100%) tr'):
    columns = tuple(cell.text for cell in row.find_all('td'))
    print(columns)
```

I used the [CSS `select()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to concisely request all table rows for your given table.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to return a very clean output.  I will look over the code and see if I have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by going through every even index and taking that element and the one after it, and putting them into a pair. The following would work as a generator:

```
def pairs(array):
    for i in range(0, len(array), 2):
        yield (array[i], array[i + 1])
```

Alternatively, if you want the function to return a list of the pairs:

```
def pairs(array):
    output = []
        for i in range(0, len(array), 2):
            output.append((array[i], array[i + 1])
```

Or, for a simpler (but less readable) program:

```
def pairs(array):
    return map(lambda index: (array[index], array[index + 1]), range(0, len(array), 2))
```

If you only want to output it in that format, there's a different way to do that directly, other than converting it to tuples and outputting those:

```
def outputPairs(array):
    for i in range(0, len(array), 2):
        print("(" + str(array[i]) + ", " + str(array[i + 1]) + ")")
```

Comment: You may want to study [Iterating over every two elements in a list](//stackoverflow.com/q/5389507) for more techniques.

Comment: Thanks, I will look over it as well.